# How to deploy solution from Visual Studio with multiple projects to Azure

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, repository-pattern, web-deployment

I am developing an MVC web app using the repository pattern, so there are many projects in one Visual Studio solution dependent on each other.

I use Visual Studio 2013

The view layer is my startup project, I have Business logic;Data Access;Model;and service layers.

The project works on my local pc but when deploy it gives error about route maps as I can only deploy one project from the solution , when I deploy I go to build publish view layer project.

Is there a way to deploy entire solution with all projects inside, and how will I do that.

Comment: Can you post the actual error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out something was wrong with my repository pattern and unit of work i redid the patterns again from scratch and it works

Answer (score 0):

You only need to deploy the website solution.

It will depend on the others and their dll's will be compiled into the website's bin folder.

The route maps issue may be a configuration problem, but you would need to post the exact error you are seeing.